# How do I remove colons from a list of MAC addresses?

Tags: regex

I'm having a hard time trying to remove the colons in a list of MAC addresses.

My file:

```
00:21:5A:28:62:BF
00:24:81:0A:04:44
```

Expected Output:

```
00215A2862BF
0024810A0444
```

Comment: why the negative votes? Fine, it's quite a naive question, but that is fine, no?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given your tags, you want to accomplish this in a shell:

```
cat file | sed s/://g
```

edit: you don't really need the `cat` either if you are reading from a file:

```
sed s/://g file
```

Comment: Isn't that a useless use of cat? sed s/://g file would work just as well without having to invoke another process. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: If you want to edit the file in place, just add the `-i` option to the sed command: `sed -i s/://g file` which will alter the file in place rather than printing the result.

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -pe "s/://g" yourfile
```

Comment: Using both -n and -p is pointless.  They do the same thing, except -p prints after executing the code, while -n does not.

Comment: Agreed, I forgot to delete the 'n'.

Answer (score 2):

tr -d ':' < file

will probably work too, though I don't have a command line handy to check the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "00:21:5A:28:62:BF" | sed -e 's/://g'
00215A2862BF
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted!